# Truncating IBM i table via OpenQuery in SQL

Tags: sql, db2, linked-server, db2-400, openquery

I'm currently trying to delete data held in a table on IBM i, via an openquery using a linked server, with the following command in SSMS;

```
DELETE FROM OpenQuery(LnkSrv,'SELECT * FROM LibA.Table1')
```

When running the above, I get an error message.

> OLE DB provider "IBMDASQL" for linked server "LnkSrv" returned message
>   "Key column information is insufficient or incorrect. Too many rows
>   were affected by update.". Msg 7345, Level 16, State 1, Line 3 The OLE
>   DB provider "IBMDASQL" for linked server "LnkSrv" could not delete from
>   table "SELECT * FROM LibA.Table1". Updating did not meet the
>   schema requirements.

Answer (score 0):

My feeling is that this is not an OpenQuery problem specifically.

I suspect that the combination of a DB2 on i 'CLRPFM' situation and the use of OLE DB to drive it is causing some sort of tangle.

Does your target table have a primary key? If not, I'd try adding one.

If you just want to clear the table on a one-off basis, you should be able to run the delete natively on IBM i.